# Customize table columns with react-table + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

For the last hours, I've found myself buried in the typings of react table without being able to understand them. I'm trying to add a custom column property for columns that are supposed to collapse on mobile screens:

```
export const COLUMNS = [
    {
        Header: "Address",
        accessor: "address",
        Filter: FreeFilter,
        disableFilters: true,
        collapse: true,
    },
]
```

The field collapse, however, does not appear on the column typings and I'm trying to add it somehow:

```
<Table variant="simple" {...getTableProps()}>
    <Thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <Tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column: any) => { <-- I don't want to use any here
                    return (
                        <Th {...column.getHeaderProps()} className={column.collapse ? "A": "B"}>
                            <span>
                                {column.render("Header")}
                            </span>
                        </Th>
                     );
                  })}
            </Tr>
          ))}
     </Thead>
     <Tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
       [...]
     </Tbody>
</Table>
```

I'm not sure how to change the typing here and would love to see an example of how to change the columns with correct typing. Maybe someone has figured it out already.

Thanks!